# Creating a simple Many to Many seeding using Django Seed library

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am facing problem while creating a seeding for my `Election` and `ElectionCandidate` models in my Django project using Django-seed library. This is what I am trying to

```py
election3 = Election.objects.get(id=3)
        positions = Position.objects.all()
        random_position = random.choice(positions)
        # Seed the ElectionCandidate model
        # Seed the ElectionCandidate model with the related CandidatePosition model
        seeder.add_entity(ElectionCandidate, number, {
            'first_name': lambda x: seeder.faker.first_name(),
            'last_name': lambda x: seeder.faker.last_name(),
            'biography': lambda x: seeder.faker.text(),
            'date_of_birth': lambda x: seeder.faker.date_of_birth(),
            'email': lambda x: seeder.faker.email(),
            'contact_number': lambda x: seeder.faker.phone_number(),
            'address': lambda x: seeder.faker.address(),
            'image': None,
            'is_incumbent': lambda x: seeder.faker.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=20),
        })


        # Execute the seeding operation for ElectionCandidate
        inserted_pks = seeder.execute()
        election_candidate_ids = inserted_pks[ElectionCandidate]
        #add candidate posisitons to ElectionCandidates via positions.set method 
        for election_candidate_id in election_candidate_ids:
            election_candidate = ElectionCandidate.objects.get(id=election_candidate_id)
            CandidatePosition.objects.create(election_candidate=election_candidate, position=random_position,election=election3)
            election_candidate.positions.set([random_position])
            
            #election3.positions.set([random_position])
        candidate_positions = CandidatePosition.objects.filter(election=election3)
        positions_for_candidate = [cp.position for cp in candidate_positions]
        election3.positions.set(positions_for_candidate)
```

and Here are my relationships

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import localdate
# from Candidate.models import ElectionCandidate


class Position(models.Model):
    position_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    position_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position_name
    



    

# Create your models here.
class Election(models.Model):
    election_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    election_date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, through='CandidatePosition', related_name='elections',blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} ({self.election_type})"
    
    @property
    def is_open(self):
        """
        Check if the election is open based on the election date.
        """
        election_datetime = timezone.make_aware(
            timezone.datetime.combine(self.election_date, timezone.datetime.min.time())
        )
        current_datetime  = localdate()
        print(current_datetime, self.election_date)
        return current_datetime == self.election_date

    @property
    def remaining_days(self):
        """
        Calculate the number of days remaining until the election.
        """
        if not self.is_open:
            return None
        election_datetime = timezone.make_aware(
            timezone.datetime.combine(self.election_date, timezone.datetime.min.time())
        )
        return (election_datetime - timezone.now()).days
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['title', 'election_type', 'election_date'], name='unique_election')
        ]


    
class ElectionCandidate(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, through='CandidatePosition',blank=True)  # Use an explicit intermediary model
    biography = models.TextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField( blank=True, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='candidate_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    is_incumbent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def elections_list(self):
        return ", ".join([cp.election.title for cp in self.positions.through.objects.filter(election_candidate=self)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name} - {self.elections_list()}"

class CandidatePosition(models.Model):
    election_candidate = models.ForeignKey(ElectionCandidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    election = models.ForeignKey(Election,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.election_candidate} - {self.position}"
```

I am facing problem which properly seeding the `ElectionCandidates` for specific election id. What I want to achieve is to select `x` number of random positions from position table and then create `y` random candidates for each position for specific election id.

**Error I am getting with current approach:** `File "C:\Users\super\Documents\Python-Projects\Django-Projects\evs_final01\Election\management\commands\electionSeeder.py", line 78, in handle election3.positions.set(random_position) File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1209, in set objs = tuple(objs) ^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'Position' object is not iterable`

I even try adding inline candidatepositions but wasn't able to do so because I didn't find the correct syntax. The error points me to set the positions via `set` method. So when I am trying to do so it is giving me error. I made the relationship field `Blank=True` then create the candidate without the position field, after that I just create a `CandidatePosition` via for loop it works. But the Election.positions remains null and Candidate.positions also remains null.

What exactly I am missing? I am new to Django as well as Database Relationships